# javascript security concern (jQuery DataTables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, datatable

I am building a web application to present data in a DataTable to our team and our customers.

When a customer is logged in, I want to hide all data except theirs. Certain rows, certain columns. When the team is logged in, I want all data visible.

If I construct one page and hide the content using DataTables `columns.visible` options depending on who is logged in, would the customer simply be able to open the browser's developer tools and make modifications to the javascript, thereby showing all the hidden data?

If this is true, do I need to filter out the data (supplied through `json` via `AJAX`) before it leaves my server?

Comment: Of course, you need to filter it server side

Comment: The only safe assumption is "if it's served, then it's visible".

Comment: He even does not need js, looking at the developer tools network log is sufficient. So filtering server side is more than needed.

Comment: @manji Thank you guys. If someone want to put that in an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a customer is logged in, I want to hide all data except theirs. Certain rows, certain columns. When the team is logged in, I want all data visible.

Let's define what you mean by "hide", do you mean:

1. Not visible on their monitor, or
2. Not sent to their machine in page source or response messages.

1) is UI-centric, while 2) is security-centric. Remember that any data you send over HTTPS will be in memory on the user's machine; even if it's not visible in the GUI, there are ways to access it.

If you hide the content using DataTables `columns.visible`, then this accomplishes 1), but not 2) since the data is still being sent, right? If the user opens their browser's dev tools and views the raw HTTP response, all the data will be there.

If that data is sensitive - say addresses and phone numbers - then this would count as a vulnerability in the application.

---

> do I need to filter out the data before it leaves my server?

If the data should not be viewable by the user for security reasons, then simply turning off its visibility is not enough: you can't be transmitting the data at all. So yes, filter it out at the server before sending the response.